# props undefined on laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I need help. I was working on a real-time notifications with laravel, pusher and vuejs. I'm trying to pass two parameters in props from blade template but they're always "undefined"

Blade template:

```
<notification :userid="{{$user->IdUsuario}}" :unreads="{{$user->unreadNotifications}}"></notification>
```

Vuejs:

```
import NotificationItem from './NotificationItem.vue';
export default {
    props: ['unreads', 'userid'],
    components: {NotificationItem},
    data() {
        return {
            unreadNotifications: this.unreads
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
    Echo.channel('App.User.' + this.userid)
    .listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(this.userid);
        let newUnreadNotifications = {
                    data: {
                        IdSalida: e.IdSalida,
                        empleado: e.empleado,
                        status: e.status
                    }
                };
            this.unreads.push(newUnreadNotifications);
    });

    }
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong :( help!

Comment: Have you tried using `userid` and `unreads` without the `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep the context of the component within your function, you need to use [Arrow Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp). Arrow functions don't have their own scope, they inherit the scope of the parent. In your case, in an arrow function you would still have `this` referring to the component.

Change

```
.listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', function (e) {
```

to

```
.listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated',(e) => {
```

and you should have the variables defined.

To keep your code organized, I would put the callback into its own method within the component and reference that function.
So your code would become something like this:

```
mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.');
    Echo.channel('App.User.' + this.userid)
       .listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', this.notificationListener);
},

methods: {
    notificationListener(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(this.userid);
        let newUnreadNotifications = {
            data: {
               IdSalida: e.IdSalida,
               empleado: e.empleado,
               status: e.status
            }
        };
        this.unreads.push(newUnreadNotifications);
    }
}
```